# Bash- passing input without shell interpreting parameter expansion chars

Tags: bash, shell, output, parameter-passing

So I have a script where I type the script.sh followed by input for a set of if-else statements. Like this:

```
    script.sh fnSw38h$?2
```

The output echoes out the input in the end.

But I noticed that $? is interpreted as 0/1 so the output would echo:

```
    fnSw38h12
```

How can I stop the shell from expanding the characters and take it face value?

I looked at something like opt noglob or something similar but they didn't work.
When I put it like this:

```
    script.sh 'fnSw38h$?2'
```

it works. But how do I capture that within single quotes ('') when I can't state variables inside it like Var='$1'

Please help!

Comment: Will `echo \$?` work?

Comment: it works, but I can't control the input to the script as people can put $? when running the script.

Answer (score 2):

#### How to pass a password to a script

I gather from the comments that the true purpose of this script is to validate a password.  **If this is an important or sensitive application, you really should be using professional security tools.**  If this application is not sensitive or this is just a learning exercise, then read on for a first introduction to the issues.

First, do **not** do this:

```
script.sh fnSw38h$?2
```

This password will appear in `ps` and be visible to any user on the system *in plain text*.

Instead, have the user type the password as input to the script, such as:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS= read -r var
```

Here, `read` will gather input from the keyboard free from shell interference and it will not appear in `ps` output.

`var` will have the password for you to verify but you really shouldn't have plain text passwords saved anywhere for you to verify against.  It is much better to put the password through a one-way hash and then compare the hash with something that you have saved in a file.  For example:

```
var=$(head -n1 | md5sum)
```

Here, `head` will read one line (the password) and pass it to `md5sum` which will convert it to a hash.  This hash can be compared with the known correct hash for this user's password.  The text returned by `head` will be exactly what the user typed, unmangled by the shell.

Actually, for a known hash algorithm, it is possible to make a reverse look-up table for common passwords.  So, the solution is to create a variable, called `salt`, that has some user dependent information:

```
var=$( { head -n1; echo "$salt"; } | md5sum)
```

The salt does not have to be kept secret.  It is just there to make look-up tables more difficult to compute.

The `md5sum` algorithm, however, has been found to have some weaknesses.  So, it should be replaced with more recent hash algorithms.  As I write, that would probably be a `sha-2` variant.

Again, if this is a sensitive application, do not use home-made tools

#### Answer to original question

> how do I capture that within single quotes ('') when I can't state variables inside it like Var='$1'

The answer is that you don't need to.  Consider, for example, this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
var=$1
echo $var
```

First, note that `$$` and `$?` are both shell variables:

```
$ echo $$ $? 
28712 0
```

Now, let's try our script:

```
$ bash ./script.sh '$$ $?'
$$ $?
```

These variables were not expanded because (1) when they appeared on the command line, they were in single-quotes, and (2) in the script, they were assigned to variables and `bash` does not expand variables *recursively*.  In other words, on the line `echo $var`, `bash` will expand `$var` to get `$$ $?` but there it stops.  It does not expand what was in `var`.

Comment: But I'm saving the output to $var, but when echoing it out it does seem to expand as I posted above- fnSw38h$?2 turns to fnSw38h12 even when I save the input in a variable.

Comment: @BruceStrafford I need more details.  If your results are different from mine, I need to know exactly what you did.

Comment: Never mind, I thought you could save input to var without single quotes being involved.

Comment: @BruceStrafford If the issue is entering a password without single-quotes, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape any dollar signs in a double-quoted string that are not meant to introduce a parameter expansion.

```
var=foo
# Pass the literal string fnSw38h$?2foo to script.sh
script.sh "fnSw38h\$?2$var"
```

Comment: I realize that, but the thing is person running the script has to just input anything, including $? or $# or & but without the double quote or \. So just scriptname followed by input (without quotes or slashes.) I'm specifically looking for a way to do that.

Comment: @BruceStrafford This is not really possible. You can instead have the script prompt the user for a value and read it in without expansion.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you are trying to do. What is entered on the command line (such as the arguments to your script) *must* be in shell syntax, and will be interpreted by the shell (according to the shell's rules) before being handed to your script.

When someone runs the command `script.sh fnSw38h$?2`, the shell parses the argument as the text "fnSw38h", followed by `$?` which means "substitute the exit status of the last command here", followed by "2". So the shell does as it's been told, it substitutes the exit status of the last command, then hands the result of that to your script.

Your script never receives "fnSw38h$?2", and cannot recover the argument in that form. It receives something like "fnSw38h02" or "fnSw38h12", because *that's what the user asked the shell to pass it*. That might not be what the user wanted to pass it, but as I said, the command must be in shell syntax, and in shell syntax an unescaped and unnquoted `$?` *means* "substitute the last exit status here".

If the user wants to pass "$?" as part of the argument, they must escape or single-quote it on the command line. Period.

Comment: So, lets say there was a script that validates password in bash. So a person inputs characters in terminal and script checks it and provides output. There is no way - other than putting characters between quotes - to escape the shell characters?

Comment: @BruceStrafford There are a variety of quoting and escaping styles that'll work, but if it's passed on the command line, it *must* be quoted/escaped appropriately. Note that if your script reads it as input (i.e. not on the command line, but as a separate input with e.g. the `read` command), then you have control over how it's parsed. `IFS= read -r  -p "Password: " password` will get you a raw string (the `IFS=` prevents whitespace trimming, and `-r` suppresses some escape interpretation). Also, use double-quotes when you refer to variables (e.g. `echo "$password"`) to prevent other problems.